# Free shipping on entire order once a specific product is added to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

Product A is added in cart and it has shipping fees. Product B is added in cart and once its added, shipping should be free. However Woocoomerce charges shipping, because Cart includes product with fees and without fees.

I Tried this code but it didn't work

```
function wcs_my_free_shipping( $is_available ) {
    global $woocommerce;
 
    // set the product ids that are eligible
    $eligible = array( '560' );
 
    // get cart contents
    $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

    // loop through the items looking for one in the eligible array
    foreach ( $cart_items as $key => $item ) {
        if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $eligible ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
 
    // nothing found return the default value
    return $is_available;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'wcs_my_free_shipping', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I used two codes

```
function wcs_my_free_shipping( $is_available ) {
global $woocommerce;

// set the product ids that are eligible
$eligible = array( '560', '562', '563', '564');


// get cart contents
$cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

// loop through the items looking for one in the eligible array
foreach ( $cart_items as $key => $item ) {
    if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $eligible ) ) {
        return true;
    }
}

// nothing found return the default value
return $is_available;
```

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'wcs_my_free_shipping', 20 );

and

```
function wcs_my_free_shipping( $is_available ) {
global $woocommerce;

// set the product ids that are eligible
$eligible = array( '560', '562', '563', '564');


// get cart contents
$cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

// loop through the items looking for one in the eligible array
foreach ( $cart_items as $key => $item ) {
    if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $eligible ) ) {
        return true;
    }
}

// nothing found return the default value
return $is_available;
```

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'wcs_my_free_shipping', 20 );